NextJS Optimizing Pagespeed TBT Mobile
I have my NextJS+TS (App Router) + Styled Components app in production with Vercel+Cloudflare, and I'm seeing good results (95+) on all metrics on desktop when using https://pagespeed.web.dev/. But on mobile performance drops to 70 to 85.
The page basically consists of a client carrousel that fetches more items if user scrolls much to right, a header and footer layout, the header has a search bar client component that auto completes. Google maps embed and everything else common styled components, and that's it.
It's a considerably small page. I am starting to think this is "mostly page speed fault"? Apparently light house only uses lab data https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/246873428?hl=en&msgid=247004997, I get perfect scores using light house, both on Chrome dev tools and npm package. Pagespeed uses lab data and real world data, but the site is not on search console yet so nobody will even search for it, no real data to really use, perhaps that's where the bad score come from?
More about the page, I have an article component that has like 15 paragraphs/headings that are styled components, doesn't sound like excess for me.
All fetches are done async and split from the page/component themselves.
I lazy load ('dynamic()') both the article and the carrousel which are the most heavy components for sure and are offscreen when user visits the page.
I use next/image and next/link.
Sometimes Pagespeed also complains about google maps embed block time of 200ms to 500ms, I see some GET fails on the console, but I see nowhere on the internet on how to make google maps embed better.
I basically went around most of nextjs production check list. Removing the carrousel seems to keep it at
80 but still no guarantees, pretty unstable.
The first items (first springboot's page) of the carrousel is fetched outside component with a server-side fetch (ApiSauce's get specifically) so I assume that helps. Regardless the client component does nothing unless the user scrolls to the max right (confirmed through debug), shouldn't have block time right?
Also the pages with bad performance are path parameterized pages, there are a lot of them, could it be because there's a big chance of having no cache on first entry of those pages, the performance's just worse?
Here's the embed's GET fail (the map still works)

